# Onsite image cropping functionality with a fixed ratio with RoR, Paperclip, S3 setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rubygems, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a way to provide a onsite image cropping functionality to the user. However,  I would only like to allow them to crop their image with a given respect ratio. The idea is similar to the square protrait cropper for some social website when you upload an avatar. Can anyone suggest a solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jCrop with paperclip in Rails. jCrop can restrict user to select square cropping. Checkout this Ryan Bates tutorial on how to integrate jCrop with paperclip http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks techvineet, That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

There's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) specifically about this - you might also consider using [gravatar](http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar) which makes everything a lot more 'hands off' for you.